# Looking for a short story about mining robots being assimilated

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

This has been bothering me for quite a while. I believe the story was posted on hackernews about 1-2 years ago. The story was about a robot in space who was mining space dust to power herself. She was originally a human woman on earth who had her brain digitized and then later was put into this space ship.

The driving force of the story is that the robots from earth and the inner solar system have come together in a hivemind and are hellbent on assimilating every last robot that exists into their system. The main character ends up accelerating towards the sun and then sleeps for a few hundred years until she is close and then tries to slingshot away at fraction the speed of light to try and escape pursuit. It continues for a bit as she tries everything she can to escape.

I remember quite a bit about the story but unfortunately what I remember doesn't lend itself to googling for it. I'm hoping someone else can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is [The Long Chase](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-long-chase/) by Geoffrey A. Landis.

> I am chased.
>
> It is impossible, stupid, unbelievable, inconceivable! I am being
>   chased.
>
> Why?
>
> Can they not leave a single free mind unconverted? In three years I
>   have reached fifteen percent of the speed of light, and it must be
>   clear that I am leaving and never coming back. Can one unconverted
>   brain be a threat to them? Must their group brain really have the
>   forced cooperation of every lump of thinking matter in the solar
>   system? Can they think that if even one free-thinking brain escapes,
>   they have lost?

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for you are the best.

Comment: @inspuration - [Glad to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)